# Using MFC, is it possible to have rows with combined data?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm using CListCtrl ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx ) to display a table with 2 columns: one has strings, the second has buttons.

Is there any way have a single column with this combination of (different) items?
Or maybe a way to hide the separator?

Edit:
Currently it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 headers (the header separators are higlighted with red circles).
I would like only one column.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Maybe an image/code of what you want would help.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can, effectively, put anything you want in only one column. Keep in mind, you're probably making the design harder than it needs to be. The deciding factor is how it will look and will the user be able to work with it.  I would try to combine the text with the button caption in a way that makes sense if you really need only one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just use Customdraw.

Handling NM_CUSTOMDRAW will allow you to customize all content in the item of the list control. Also it will allow you to draw a button in the specific control instead of creating a new window inside the list control. NM_CUSTOMDRAW is easy to use and much simpler than owner draw functionality.

Here two articles that describe this stuff.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4195/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-I.htm

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4199/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-II.htm

Comment: Link-only answers discouraged. Should the referenced resources become unavailable at some point, this answer will be rendered useless. Please take the time to sum up the procedures, to make the answer self-contained.

Comment: I added some more lines.